# R: Calculating the Number of Phone Calls Every Hour

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, data-cleaning

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
Call No.  Arrival Time  Call Length (in hrs) ...
================================================
1         0.01          0.061 
2         0.08          0.05
3         0.10                                   (Busy/Unanswered)
4         0.15          0.42
...
10        1.03          0.36
11        1.09          0.72
...
```

I want to count the number of phone calls each hour (e.g. number of successful phone calls from arrival times [0, 1), [1, 2), [2, 3), etc.

There are some empty values in the call length column, indicating that the phone line was busy, so the call went unanswered. I basically want to count the nonempty occurrences of the call length and group them by hour by summing them. How can I do this using dataframe operations in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chiming in with a base R solution

```
dat <- data.frame(`Call No.` = c(1,2,3,4,10,11), 
           `Arrival Time` = c(0.01,0.08,0.10,0.15,1.03,1.09),
           `Call Length (in hrs)` = c(0.61, 0.05, NA, 0.42, 0.36, 0.72), 
           check.names = F) # to keep the spaces
# filter out NAs
dat2 <- dat[complete.cases(dat),]
# add an hour variable
dat2$hour <- floor(dat2$`Arrival Time`)

# for fun, create a function that takes in a df
count_and_sum <- function(df){
  return(data.frame(hour = df$hour[1], # assumes we will pass it dfs with 1 hour only
             answered_calls =   nrow(df),
             total_call_time_hrs = sum(df$`Call Length (in hrs)`)))
}

# use split to separate the data into a list of data.frames by hour 
# added a step but might be better to do in one row for memory
splitted <- split(dat2, dat2$hour, drop= T) 
# use sapply to apply our function to each element of the splitted list
# and transpose to make the output the right orientation
t(sapply(splitted, count_and_sum))
#  hour answered_calls total_call_time_hrs
#0 0    3              1.08               
#1 1    2              1.08
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Hour = round(`Arrival Time`)) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(Total_phone_calls = 
       sum(complete.cases(`Call Length (in hrs)`)))
```

Or remove the `NA` elements in the `Call Length (in hrs))` column and use `n()` or `count`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   drop_na(`Call Length (in hrs)`) %>%
   count(Hour = round(`Arrival Time`))
```

Comment: Hi @akrun - looks like I get the same value for every hour of Avg_phone_calls. What can I do to just count the number of phone calls in hour 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: @324 If you want the count without the missing values, use `sum` instead of `mean`

Comment: I still get the same value for every hour (e.g., ` Hour
<dbl>
AvgPhoneCalls
<int>
0 48   
1 48   
2 48   
3 48   
4 48   
5 48   
6 48   
7 48   
8 48  `)

Comment: 48 is the total number of answered calls in my dataset. This is not separating by hour.

Comment: @324  Maybe the logic you mentioned is not clear.  What I understand is to `round` the  `Arrival Time` to get the `Hour` and then get the count of non-NA elementse in `Call Length`

Comment: @324 Do you have NA elements or something like `(Busy/Unanswered)` in place or blanks `""`)

Comment: I have NAs in place of blanks in the Call Length column

Comment: @324 If you can update with the structure of a subset of data, it may be more clear. i.e. `dput(head(df1, 20))`, copy the output of structure and edit in your post

Comment: @324 In many cases, it can be a quoted `"NA"` which will not be picked up in complete.cases or drop_na

Comment: I have another binary column indicating whether the call was answered/completed (0 if the call was not answered, 1 if it was). Perhaps leveraging this might help

Comment: @324 in that case, use `summarise(Total_phone_calls = sum(binary_col, na.rm = TRUE))`.  If your NA were unquoted, my solutions should have worked

Comment: @324 Also, can you try `dplyr::summarise(...)` instead of just `summarise` as `plyr` summarise could have masked the dplyr summarise

Comment: unfortunately the same issue... calls %>%
  group_by(Hour) %>%
  summarise(PhoneCalls = sum(calls$Busy., na.rm = TRUE)) I get the same number for every hour (Hour = round(calls$Arrival.time))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248678/discussion-between-324-and-akrun).

Comment: @324 you are not using the code I showed.  You have taken the full column with `calls$Busy`, thus getting the count of whole non-NA lements.  It should be just `sum(Busy,..`

Comment: Ah thank you. Silly me. That did the trick